# Not able to use non stubbed method with receive_message_chain rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a strange issue with receive_message_chain rspec 3.6

```
 allow_any_instance_of(Order).to receive_message_chain('line_items.find') 
{LineItem.first}
```

When i do a order.line_items instead of returning a collection it returns me a `<Double (anonymous)>` object which is not what i wanted.

Any suggestions??

Comment: What is your RSpec and the code you want to test? What do expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: Its a problem in insolation. After receive_message_chain('a.b.c') I cannot use a.b.d anymore @JagdeepSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tell RSpec to set `receive_message_chain('line_items.find')` on a specific object, it needs set the correct stubs in place for the chain to work.

First RSpec stubs the method `line_items` on the object. Next it needs to stub the method `find`, but this method needs to be stubbed on the return value of the method `line_items`. Since we stubbed that method, RSpec needs to come up with a some return value, that can be the target of the stubbing.

So RSpec sets the return value of the method `line_items` to be an anonymous double that has the the method `find` stubbed. Because of this once you set the `receive_message_chain` with `'line_items.find'`, the object will always return an anonymous double when `line_items` is called. And since you use `allow_any_instance_of`, this means that the method `line_items` is now stubbed on all the instances of `Order`.

I would recommend thinking about trying to remove the uses of `allow_any_instance_of` and `receive_message_chain` from your specs if it is possible, since they are really shortcuts to be used in specs if you really cannot change the design of your code. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains

However if that is not possible, you can remove the `receive_message_chain` and set the chain yourself.

```
line_items_stub = double 
# or line_items_stub = Order.new.line_items
# or line_items_stub = [LineItem.new, LineItem.new]
# or line_items_stub = the object that you want

allow_any_instance_of(Order).
  to receive(:line_items).
  and_return(line_items_stub)
allow(line_items_stub).to receive(:find)
```

If you were able to remove the `allow_any_instance_of` you could use [`and_call_original`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation) to call the for real implementation of line_items on that concrete instance you are stubbing the message_chain on.

Comment: makes a lot of sense.